# The format of a message during Web synchronization was invalid. Ensure that replication components are properly configured at the Web server.

Tags: sql-server-2012, merge-replication

Getting the error "**The format of a message during Web synchronization was invalid. Ensure that replication components are properly configured at the Web server"** in SQL server 2012 using merge replication.

We have tried changing the registry key value

WebSyncMaxXmlSize to 4Gb but still getting the same error. It fails when we are using large chunk of data failing at 3100 chunks

Answer (score 0):

Add key under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server -> 100 -> ***Replication***
Under that key create DWORD: ***WebSyncMaxXmlSize***
Value decimal: ***2000000***

Yes it stands for SQL 2008, but this works for 2012 too.